# How to change the default value for border-radius on buttons in sencha touch 2?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm usin Sencha Touch 2, I need to change the default border-radius for the buttons in my app.

How can  MAKE IT? PLEASE PROVIDE ME A SAMPLE OF CODE.

THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this :

```
.x-button {
  border-radius:0.2em !important;
}
```

Only if you are sure you wanna change the border-radius of every single button in your app.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

include

```
$button-radius: '2px';
```

in your custom-theme.scss file

then compile the scss file using the command compass compile.